# Rails Routing not passing ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, my first, I am having issues with finding the right routing. The routing I have does not pass the variable @annotation nor the id.

Using

```
<%= link_to 'Annotate', annotate_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

I want to open a page

Routes - amongst other, these are the routes I have tried for this resource:

```
resources :annotations do
    resources :comments
    get "annotate", on: :member
```

and

```
get "annotations/:id/annotate" => "annotations#annotate", as: 'annotate'
```

The later one opens the page, using url `http://localhost:3000/annotations/7/annotate` - yet I get an error message like *undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass* when using `<%= @annotation.name %>`

In my controller, I have (not complete):

```
private

def annotate
  @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
end
```

How to go about?

Comment: can you post the log of what params the call is passing to controller

Comment: why is your `annotate` method private in the controller ?

Comment: @fanta, should it not be private?

Comment: @Deepak : Processing by AnnotationsController#annotate as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}

Comment: change the method public it's an action it is supposed to be public

Comment: @fanta - changing it from private to public fixed it. Thanks. Think I now better understand what private means (am new to ruby and RoR)